# about wrap text in ContentDialogResult in winphone 8.1 RT

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have long string and show it in ContentDialogResult as

```
var dlg = new ContentDialog()
        {
            Title = sTitle,
            Content = "This is very long string and i want wrap it but it only appear in 1 line on content of ContentDialogResult. Please help me!",
            PrimaryButtonText = sTextBtnMain,
            SecondaryButtonText = sTextBtnSub
        };
```

but it only show on 1 line and no wrap. How i can wrap it **without custom xaml for ContentDialogResult**.

Thanks for all support!

Comment: Just look at the example code in the MSDN library for ContentDialog.  Note the use of TextBlock.

Comment: @HansPassant can u show me exactly, I find but it show custom xaml  for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ContentDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.aspx) accepts any object as Title and Content property. So, create [TextBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock.aspx), add [TextWrapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textblock.textwrapping.Aspx) property and pass it to Content instead of string object. It will work.

```
        TextBlock txtBlock = new TextBlock();
        txtBlock.Text = "This is very long string and i want wrap it but it only appear in 1 line on content of ContentDialogResult. Please help me!";
        txtBlock.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;

        ContentDialog dialog = new ContentDialog()
        {
             Title = sTitle,
             Content = txtBlock,
             PrimaryButtonText = sTextBtnMain,
             SecondaryButtonText = sTextBtnSub
        };
```